# Are UserDefaults and ApplicationSupportDirectory safe against external manipulation?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, nsuserdefaults

I use standard `UserDefaults` and default `applicationSupportDirectory`:

```
userDefaults.set(level, forKey: solvedLevel)

let fileURL = try FileManager.default
    .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    .appendingPathComponent("somethingToSave.json")
try JSONEncoder().encode(myObject)
    .write(to: fileURL)
```

I'm wondering if these files are safe against external manipulation. Is a user (with and without jailbreak) able to change the content of the files for example to change the current level or the json file?

For Application Support Directory I found that the content is not visible for users (I suggest that that's only true for no jailbreak?).

For User Defaults I only found the "Sandbox Considerations" [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults). But I guess that's only true for non jailbreaked devices, too?

Comment: The user has root privileges on a jailbroken device, so they can change literally anything they want. On a non-jailbroken device it's complicated to modify these files, but it's not entirely impossible. Why do you care about this? In general, if you have to mistrust the user, you can also absolutely not rely on his device doing what you think it does.

Comment: I have data that is between "needs to be 100% safe" and "no problem if everyone can see it" so I would not care if only users on jailbreaked devices could see/change them but I guess then I will encrypt them to make sure it is safe.